# Does this pushdown automaton describe the language {$a^n b^n c^i \in \{a,b,c\}^*\ |\ n \ge 0,i\ge 0$}?

Tags: pushdown-automata

I've just been learning about pushdown automata and I'm trying to create one that describe the following language:

{$a^n b^n c^i \in \{a,b,c\}^*\ |\ n \ge 0,i\ge 0$}

What I have is the following:

(state, symbol, top of stack), (next state, what goes to stack).

$(s,$e$,$e$),(f,$e$)$

$(s,a,$e$),(s,d)$

$(f,b,d),(f,$e$)$

$(f,c,$e$),(f,$e$)$

Where $s$ is the starting state, $f$ is the final state and e is the empty word.

Do I have the right idea? My worry is sending the automata to the final state while there are still entries in the stack - is that allowed?

Comment: Is the notation (state, symbol, top of stack), (next state, what goes to stack)?

Comment: For one, 2 states is not enough. Also, there are many combinations you don't consider.

Comment: Yes, that is the notation; sorry for not being clearer. Could you give me an example of a combination that I don't consider?

Comment: Well, what about (s, a, d)? Or does `e` mean *anything*  and not *empty stack*? Also, (s, b, \*). Maybe unless your pda is non deterministic... You should specify the details of your model - is it deterministic, is it accepted by state, or by empty stack, does `e` in stack mean *nothing*, *anything* or just `e`, does the absence of a rule mean that it leads into a hidden state `r` (for reject)?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't realise there were different types. The PDA is non-deterministic; e means nothing; it seems that we're required to have a final state _and_ an empty stack (is that a possible requirement?); the absence of a rule does indeed lead to a rejection. I have noticed some immediate failures of my PDA (an input of acb being one of them) and am constructing a new one now.

Answer (score 1):

As I am (not) yet certain of the PDA model you are using, I will not comment on correctness of your construction, but I have a general remark on PDA.

There happen to be two generic ways of defining languages for PDA: by final state and by empty stack. Let a configuration be a description of the PDA, its (yet unprocessed) tape, state, stack.

Using *final state acceptance* means that we accept any word that leads from the initial configuration of the automaton to a configuration that is in a final state (no matter what is the contents of the stack) after reading the complete input.
Similarly, *empty stack acceptance* means that we accept any word that leads from the initial configuration of the automaton to a configuration in which the stack is empty (no matter what is the state) after reading the complete input.

By standard constructions one is able to change a PDA into an equivalent one using the other acceptance type. so for practical reasons the two notions are interchangeable. When dealing with technicalities (in case of deterministic automata for instance) the acceptance type *does* matter.

In conclusion: if you are using final state acceptance, then do not worry about remaining stack symbols.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I think my PDA is incorrect so I will try and construct another and will come back when I have it.